# Is it OK to flag exact duplicate answers as Very Low Quality?

Tags: discussion, answers, flags, vote-to-delete, duplicate-answers

Is it OK to flag *exact* duplicate answers as Very Low Quality? One of my privileges as a [20k+ trusted user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) is the ability to vote to delete answers with a negative score. The help center says that I may use this privilege to vote to delete answers when

> - The answer is extremely low quality: There is little to no scope for improvement.
> - The answer doesn't attempt to answer the question; it may be a comment or a separate question altogether.

I've interpreted "extremely low quality" to include duplicate answers, though [not everyone agrees on what answers should be considered as "duplicates"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171501/163250).

For the sake of this question, though, let's just say that I do find an *exact, verbatim* duplicate answer, and I vote to delete it. Is it then OK to also flag it as Very Low Quality, so that I can get help from other users to also delete the answer? I've noticed that it can take days or weeks for some answers to get the 3 required votes for deletion, so that's why I was wondering if it's OK to flag it to draw additional attention to it.

**Or is deleting duplicate answers like this an abuse of the privilege?** I know that you can attempt to make a case to a moderator in a flag that an answer is a duplicate, but since I have the ability as a trusted user to remove negative score answers myself, I thought that this might be an appropriate use, instead of adding more work for moderators.

### Example

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24679290/456814) five days ago and voted to delete it:

> Here is how I rename a tag old to new:
>
> git tag new_tag old_tag
>
> git tag -d old_tag
>
> git push origin :refs/tags/old_tag
>
> git push --tags
>
> The colon in the push command removes the tag from the remote
>   repository. If you don't do this, git will create the old tag on your
>   machine when you pull.
>
> It is working.

because it's a near verbatim copy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5719854/456814):

> Here is how I rename a tag `old` to `new`:
>
> ```
> git tag new old
> git tag -d old
> git push origin :refs/tags/old
> git push --tags
> ```
>
> The colon in the push command removes the tag from the remote
>   repository. If you don't do this, git will create the old tag on your
>   machine when you pull.

If you look at [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24679290/456814) for the duplicate, the author even made some trivial variable name changes to (unsuccessfully) attempt to make the answer not a duplicate.

I voted to delete 5 days ago, and no one else has voted to delete it since then. I even left a comment pointing out that it was an exact duplicate, with a link to the other answer. Is it OK to flag it as Very Low Quality too?

Comment: I usually flag as "other" to make sure that a moderator sees it. Most of the time, the robo-reviewers in the low-quality queue click "Looks OK" because they see a code block, resulting in my flag being disputed (even with a comment on the post saying that it's a duplicate of another answer).

Comment: I use the custom flag and inform mods that it's plagiarism. They remove it. Ofcourse, am a low-rep user with no delete privilege, so flagging is the only option for me :-) I flagged the answer you mentioned for plagiarism too.

Comment: Actually, I take back saying it's not VLQ; I'm actually not sure. Properly attributed, the answer is essentially the top-voted answer in a quote block, which amounts to nothing but noise. Whether this can be considered damaging to SO's quality can be debated, especially since such an answer is almost certainly going to be hidden beneath many other answers. I still think such an answer shouldn't exist; whether it's VLQ, though, and warrants a mod's attention... I don't know.

Comment: @user3580294 it would not be good to simply edit in the attribution, in my opinion. Doing so means the answer can be voted on, and new duplicate answers have an unfortunate habit of being ***voted up***, because users ***don't read*** the existing answers. Allowing users to gain rep by just verbatim copying existing answers is an extremely strong incentive to continue posting crap like this, in my opinion.

Comment: @Cupcake No, it certainly wouldn't be *good*. I honestly don't know what exactly I'm hung up on. I agree with you, but just something doesn't sit well... My apologies that I can't come up with concrete reasons.

Comment: @user3580294 Does it really make sense to allow two answers that state the same thing verbatim just because the second one attributes the first? What if even more users come along doing the same thing, attributing all of the previous answers? Makes much more sense to just leave the first alone and delete the others. It's not even about letting the others get rep; it's about there being no reason to allow an answer that doesn't bring anything new to the table (Exception: it's trying to draw from everybody else to make one canonical answer with everything on it. Properly attributed, of course)

Comment: @DennisMeng Well, I did say "I still think such an answer shouldn't exist", so I think my position on this is pretty clear. I'm still trying to figure out what I'm getting hung up on.

Comment: As in, we're agreeing that these "answers" shouldn't exist, but are debating over exactly how to flag them so that we can be rid of them?

Comment: Yes. Although I think I'm probably the only one who's not sure that they are VLQ.

Comment: I guess my two cents is that I would have flagged for moderator attention (and explained how I knew it was a dupe), though I admit, if someone flagged as VLQ and as a reviewer I can clearly see that the post is a dupe, I'd still "recommend deletion"

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The "very low quality" flag option does not tell us anything about the fact that the answer is a copy. It tells us that the answer is... well, very low quality. Plus if an answer were low quality, nobody would want to copy it in the first place, so without context a reviewer would simply see a good answer, rather than a lazy copy of a good answer, and dismiss the flag as invalid since what they see clearly contradicts the flag.

If you want to tell us that an answer is a duplicate, you will have to state that explicitly. Do not use the canned flag options, especially when they simply do not describe the real problem clearly and correctly.

I'd like to take this opportunity to remind users flagging duplicate posts to always specify where exactly the post was duplicated from, ideally with a direct link to the source.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that I shouldn't use VLQ flags for this purpose now. Still though, I feel that if I have the ability to delete negative scored answers, I should do that instead of requiring mod intervention. It's just tough if you can't find 2 other users to vote with you.

Comment: @Cupcake: The problem is that these cases aren't always clear cut. Some people copy answers as a way of quoting them to say thanks, but it's not clear to a reviewer or a moderator that that's their intention and the answer is therefore NAA. Other people copy answers for reasons no one could possibly guess, but again without context it doesn't appear to a reviewer that the answer is copied unless you specifically say so.

Comment: @Cupcake: One alternative would be to implement a brand new flag option for duplicate answers for high-rep users to review, but I don't know if the devs would be on board with that. You could post a feature request.

Comment: Well, how many days deep is the mod-only flag queue? I think that's one of the most important factors for deciding on that.