# OK to leave months-late duplicate answers lying around?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, specific-answer, duplicate-answers

[Moderator says to flag months-late answers that roughly duplicate existing answers for mod attention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274826/). Recently I flagged a [fairly blatant duplicate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12680300/) with "Late duplicate answers don't need to be left around, even if positively scored; please delete accordingly."

It was declined by a diamond, despite the flag message, the fact that everything in it (number, doc link, and all) is already in the other answer posted months earlier, and the highly-upvoted comment pointing that out.

[Is it OK to flag exact duplicate answers as Very Low Quality?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266236/is-it-ok-to-flag-exact-duplicate-answers-as-very-low-quality) suggests my error may have been in not explicitly linking to the other answer… but the question only has two answers, so dotting that i seems kind of silly.

Is that really what's supposed to happen? I'm a little vexed by this.

Comment: Maybe because while the answer was posted five months late, it's three *years* old at this point. More time has passed since that answer was posted than the question's age at the time it was posted.

Comment: @BoltClock: Well, OK, I can see why that would be a good reason not to go on a hunt for these, but I ran across this thing in (if memory serves) a review queue, and under the circumstances it seems odd to just say "s'ok, grandfather clause it all in!" with a declination.

Comment: Yeah, I would have deleted that in a heartbeat...

Comment: Curiously, [it took only one user to vet it out of the Late Answers queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/738646) (has it always worked that way?). The community was given ample opportunity at the start to clean it up but they chose to leave it. Probably because it didn't bother to display other, similar-looking answers so it seemed like a proper answer on its own, just posted late (which becomes even more exasperating when you realize the earlier answer also came ridiculously late, with the purpose of debunking the earliest answers).

Comment: @BoltClock: Used to be LA and FP were multi-reviewer queues, but there was so much unwarranted voting they cut it to just one. When Triage came along they realized the real solution: only allow the last reviewer to vote.

Comment: Ugh. You can "always" count on reviewers to do a good job.

Comment: @BoltClock: That's a link-only comment! Deleting! ;)

Comment: I had a flag declined on a duplicate late (and poor) answer a while ago. My [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281186/flag-declined-on-late-duplicate-answer) about it was also downvoted and closed and later deleted by Community. The lesson I took from it was that answer duplication was not considered to be an issue. Along with the silly interpretation by the moderators of the "not an answer" flag, this mostly turned me off flagging and reviewing, as there didn't seem to be much I could do to actually clean up bad answers (and I wasn't that interested in handling questions).

Comment: @corsair992: I can see why NAA would easily be declined (by diamond or LQP reviewers), barring maybe a very descriptive comment left. But in this case, there was a happy ending: the post is quite gone.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: One down. 9001 more to go.

Comment: **No**, not OK.

Comment: By the way, I posted a feature suggestion aimed to reduce the amount of duplicate answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270027/encourage-deleting-ones-own-answer-in-favor-of-another-one-in-order-to-reduce-t