# What to do in gold dupehammer disagreement

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

This seems like a question which *should* have a duplicate, but I couldn't find it.

**My question is about process.** The below question is just an example. Please do not focus on whether or not the question linked below is in fact a duplicate.

This is what happened:

1. I initially closed this question as a duplicate: [get means and SEM in one df with pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49512034/get-means-and-sem-in-one-df-with-pandas-groupby).
2. It was then re-opened and answered by another gold badge holder in a relevant tag.
3. I then [posted a Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365180/duplicates-in-the-context-of-data-manipulation) detailing the issue *and* flagged for a moderator to investigate with a link to the Meta. The Meta question is unanswered. The flag is declined - *flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention*.

What exactly is the process? Who adjudicates on whether the question is a duplicate?

The answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/359061/563532) says:

> Re-opening properly closed dupes in order to answer them is not
>   acceptable. It's textbook abuse of one's privileges.
>
> Mod-flag the answer. These flags will add up and eventually will
>   result in a suspension if the user doesn't change their behavior.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You believe the question should be closed. The other party disagrees. The only thing that makes this different is that you both have gold-badge powers. But otherwise, you wouldn't involve moderators for dealing with two people who disagree about a question being a duplicate.

So why would that be appropriate now? And since the moderators declined your flag, you should take that as an indication that there is nothing here that is objectionable. There's simply you disagreeing with someone else about whether the question is a dupe.

Nothing to see here.

> Who adjudicates on whether the question is a duplicate?

As with everything, the *community* does. If more members of the community decide the question should be closed as a duplicate, then it will be. That's the way it works.

Comment: I can wholeheartedly accept this answer, except for one issue. The highly upvoted answer that I quote in my question suggests I *should* flag for a mod. Am I misinterpreting that answer, or do you believe that answer is incorrect?

Comment: @jpp: It says "properly closed dupe"; you and the other person disagree with whether the question was "properly closed". That's not something worth bothering the moderators over.

Comment: I see. Understood. So don't flag unless there's *actually a war*, which can only happen without the gold badge holders who disagreed at the beginning. Nice incentive to answer duplicates.

Comment: @jpp: You can flag whenever you want. Just don't be surprised if moderators aren't going to waste their time over a simple 2-person disagreement rather than a significant problem. Moderators should step in when something has gone *wrong*, not when something has not gone the way one person things it should.

Comment: What constitutes a *properly closed dupe* if every party involved will always think their action is the proper one?

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic: Presumably, it's a judgment call. A moderator looked at the flagged question and decided that it wasn't a "properly closed dupe". Or at the very least that it was sufficiently questionable not to take action.

Comment: I have to un-accept this answer, sorry. I just read an answer from a mod, which suggests a [process for flagging duplicates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266238/9209546) with no reference to how many people agree / disagree / care.

Comment: @jpp: That's for duplicate *answers*, for which there is no close voting.

Answer (score 8):

Hmm.

I don't see much of a "war" here.  I see a close vote and a reopen vote.

If there was something like this question was closed like, three or four times and reopened four or five times, then *that'd* be a good point for a moderator to intervene...but right now you should focus on convincing both the OP and the reopener as to why this question actually *is* a dupe.

Comment: Note, that for "wars" to occur, there need to be two willing parties. The system around the dupe-hammer was designed such as you only get one vote each way, for reopening or closing.

Comment: @Braiam:  I'd say that this is less a "war" and more of a "squabble".  When reinforcements start getting called in, *then* it starts to escalate into something more.  No such reinforcements have intervened here.

Comment: @Makoto, OP doesn't care whether it's a dup or not - he's got his answer. As per Meta, the answerer *admits* it's a dup of 2-3 answers, he just doesn't agree with the idea of closing as a duplicate of more than one post (which is actually one of the reasons for the feature). Of course, a dup war is impossible between 2 gold badge holders, as Braiam explained.